# Rotating a 4 bit integer

Tags: java

I have an int `00000000000000000000000000001101` which represents 13 in base ten. I am trying to circular rotate the the bits by treating the 32 bit integer as a 4 bit integer because if I rotate the integer the value becomes very large. My desired answer after a right rotation of 2 for the above example would be `00000000000000000000000000000111` which is 7 in base 10.

Any help on doing this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not quite sure. But who 1101 becomes 0111 when you right rotate it?

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne He want to rotate a four bit integer. Initial `1101`. First rotation `1110`, Second rotation `0111`. Voilà.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To rotate the lower 4 bits to the right by `n`, where `n` is 1, 2, or 3:

```
((x >> n) | (x << (4-n))) & 0xF;
```

The first part shifts the leftmost 4-n bits to the right; the second part shifts the rightmost n bits to the left.  Then you `or` them together, and use `& 0xF` to zero extra bits that may have been set by the left shift.

Comment: I'm guessing I can generalize to other bit integers by changing the 4-n to something like 20-n for a 20 bit integer?

Comment: Yes.  You also have to change the mask (`0xF`).  If `b` is the number of bits, the mask is `(1<<b)-1`.  Basically, the mask is the number whose low-order `b` bits are all 1.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

`x = (x >> 2) | ((x & 3) << 2);`

This is just simulating the rotation via shifts and masks. I don't think there is anything better you could do, short of maybe making a lookup table (which may not actually be better); the CPU doesn't have opcodes for natively dealing with nybbles.

Comment: Can your answer be generalized to other cases such as a 10, 15, 24 bit integer etc? I generated a bunch of test cases by hand using the values above.

Comment: Yes, it could be. Why don't you try it and if you get stuck, show your code so we can help.

Comment: Will do that. I just wanted to ask before I get started.